# Who names the powers of Mangekyō Sharingan?

Tags: naruto

Considering that Obito, Kakashi and Madara all knew the name of Kamui without someone telling them, can we conclude that those who have the Mangekyō Sharingan know the name of its exclusive power? (Obito's Kamui, Shisui's Kotoamatsukami, Itachi's Amaterasu and Tsukuyomi, Sasuke's Amaterasu and Blaze Release: Kagutsuchi, and everyone's Susanoo)

Comment: Feel free to ask the other question in a new question.

Comment: That's OK. I'll do it later. This one comes first.

Comment: Don't lie... you are really Obito aren't you? We already know the real Madara Uchiha here...

Comment: You got me... Guess I'll go home then... :(

Comment: Anybody know anything?

Comment: My guess is that it's mostly laziness on the part of the writer; they wanted it to be consistent, and the easiest way to do that is to just have everyone use the same names for things, even if there's no logical way for them to know.

Comment: @Madara The best I can do is speculate that some eye abilities are hereditory.  That is why both Sasuke and his brother have the black flames.  Some great great grandfather of Obito who was a contemporary or predecessor of Madara had a simular ability with the same name.  They know the name because they have at least a limited memory of decriptions of the ability.  Unfortunately it does not appear the name is merely descriptive as "fire ball" or "interspacetravellythingy" would be.

Comment: That would be totally wrong since Amaterasu was passed down to Sasuke by his brother as pointed out by Madara when he explained the truth of Itachi to him. Also, there were only few people who awakened the Mangekyo Sharingan throughout the history. I still think those who have the power will realize what its original power's name is as they will have the say it (even sometimes involuntarily) when using it.

Comment: **Who got them first name them first, other follows** theory.

Comment: On Kakashi's first encounter with Tobi (without knowing he is Obito), he thought to himself "His Mangekyo Sharingan's ability is the same as my Kamui" and no one told Madara the name of Kamui when he used it and said the name...

Comment: @Madara I didn't catch that... thanks.... that means we are back to bad writing...

Comment: What part did you miss exactly my friend? That's the original question expressed differently... Forget this comment. I asked if anyone knew the answer to the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, only the ones with the Mangekyō Sharingan know the names of their techniques.

Taking an example, Obito and Kakashi had Obito's Mangekyō Sharingan. And they had the same Mangekyō technique (Kamui). Considering that Kakashi and Obito never saw each other or trained together after they awakened the Mangekyō, it is not a coincidence that both call their technique "Kamui".

In raw terms (sorry for the bad example), consider the Mangekyō Sharingan as a system, and it has two processes: A.exe and B.exe (the Mangekyō techniques). The two processes are already named, installed and stored in the system. And for the user to access it, all it needs is the fulfilment of the system requirements (loss of a loved one). So, when the uses has access to the processes, they naturally will know what to call it, since its already named and stored.

I hope this answers **how the users *know* the names of their MS techniques**. Nothing can be said about *how the MS techniques are named* because the current level of evidence is inconclusive.

Comment: About that last comment, when Madara tried to take away his Rinnegan from Obito, Obito used Kamui to get intangible, this surprised Madara and he said: "I passed through you. That's you right eye's original ability." Also, he heard Obito/Kakashi say "Kamui" when trying to take Naruto and Sakura to the other dimension...

Comment: Oh I didn't know about that. Thanks for the info. Answer updated :)